# following code(even as sum of two primes) gives a segmentatioon error.plz help me to sort out that

Tags: c++11

```
vector <int> v(2);
int isprime(int n) {
    for(int i=2;i<=sqrt(n);i++)
    {   
        if(n%i==0)
            return 0;
    }
    if(n==1)
        return 0;
    else
        return 1;    
}

vector<int> Solution::primesum(int n)//this the function which return a vector  array of two primes.        
{   
     //following for loop checks for  number less than n if prime

     for(int i=3;i<n;i++)
     {
        if(isprime(i)==1 && isprime(n-i)==1)
        {
            v.push_back(i);
            v.push_back(n-i);
            return v;
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: If `primesum` doesn't find the right pair of integers, it exhibits undefined behavior, by way of falling off the end without executing a `return` statement.

Comment: corrected .now there is no segmentation fault but the code is not giving correct solution.for ex-> for input 378 expected output is 5,373 but my code return 3,181,5,373 .can you sort out that problem also....

Answer (score 0):

Probably, you should call `v.clear()` at the beginning of `Solution::primesum`. And, of course, always return a value, as mentioned in comments.

One more thing: I would not recommend you returning global variable in function. It's better to create local vector and then return it.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few fixes done in the following code and you may work on it further:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int isprime(int n) {
    for(int i=2;i<=sqrt(n);i++) {   
        if(n%i==0)
            return 0;
    }
    if(n==1)
        return 0;
//    else // <- should remove this line: all routs should return a value
        return 1;    
}

vector<int> primesum(int n)//this the function which return a vector  array of two primes.        
{   
    vector<int> v; //<- define v here rather than outide the function.
                   //<- Note also that it's not vector<int> v(2); as you use push_back later.
     for(int i=3;i<n;i++)
     {
        if(isprime(i)==1 && isprime(n-i)==1)
        {
            v.push_back(i);
            v.push_back(n-i);
            return v;
        }            
    }
    return v; // Again all routs should return a value.
}


int main() {
    auto vec = primesum(378);

    for(auto v : vec) {
        cout << v << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The reason you get 4 values in the vector rather than 2 is that you initialize as `vector<int> v(2);` so it already has 2 element now. Then you `push_back` 2 extra element later.

[Live demo](http://ideone.com/AG7Ch7)